# Asset Management (CSS/Javascript) with lots of widgets?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, minify

I'm currently porting an internal web portal from Web Forms to MVC. Most programs are provided as small widgets/gadgets. Each user typically has 10-15 widgets that they use.

I've been unable to find a library to combine and minify our javascript/css files from a set of partial views that are determined at runtime.

Each user could have a different set of javascript files, depending on their added widgets. They could change this set of files by adding a new widget to their page. There's far too many widgets for us to include all of the javascripts/stylesheets into one big file.

I've currently looked at:

- SquishIt (Doesn't provide a good method to include javascript/css into the head tag from partial views)
- SquishIt - MVC Contrib (no longer supported, but it meets our needs)
- Cassette (Tries to combine javascript/css from all of our widgets, not just the files that the user has loaded. Otherwise, it minifies each widget separately. IE doesn't allow us to have that many external stylesheets)

Comment: Why are you not considering things like Dojo Toolkit which has exactly what you require built in?  Just output marked-up pages and Dojo will parse the HTML, load the required script files async, and create the widgets automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [RequestReduce.com](http://RequestReduce.com). It will dynamically minify/bundle your css and js at runtime without requiring any kind of config or code to tell it where and what js/css to include. It should just find it on its own. Does it all by analyzing the response and then caching the reduced files. Ideally, just add the module and you are done.